# sqlalchemy add entity from a subquery

Tags: python, join, sqlalchemy, subquery

I want to use `outerjoin` operation on a `subquery` and also include values from the subquery also.

**My code**

```
q_responses = session.query(Candidate, CandidateProfile)
             .join(CandidateProfile, CandidateProfile.candidate_id == Candidate.id)

subq = (session.query(AppAction.candidate_id, Activity.archived)\
        .join(Activity, and_(AppAction.candidate_id == Activity.candidate_id, 
                             Activity.archived == 1)))\
        .subquery("subq")
responses = q_responses.outerjoin(subq, Candidate.id == subq.c.candidate_id).all()
```

So I get the result in this format

```
(Candidate, CandidateProfile)
```

But I also want to include the **archived** value from subquery in the result.

By reading many relevant posts from the internet, I have tried

1. `add_entity(subq.c.archived)`
2. `with_entities`
3. `add_column`
4. `select_from`

But all those have resulted in some error.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 3):

Please share your error for when you try `add_column`. The code below should work just fine (assuming that it does work without like which contains `add_column`):

```
responses = (
    q_responses
    .add_column(subq.c.archived)  # @new
    .outerjoin(subq, Candidate.id == subq.c.candidate_id)
).all()
```

Also you could have created a query straight away with this column included:

```
subq = (
    session.query(AppAction.candidate_id, Activity.archived)
    .join(Activity, and_(AppAction.candidate_id == Activity.candidate_id,
                         Activity.archived == 1))
).subquery("subq")

q_responses = (
    session.query(Candidate, CandidateProfile, subq.c.archived)
    .join(CandidateProfile, CandidateProfile.candidate_id == Candidate.id)
    .outerjoin(subq, Candidate.id == subq.c.candidate_id)
).all()
```

Comment: Thanks! I can now get those values from subquery to the outer query.